# Object.defineProperty called on non-object With Nuxt3 and Vuelidate

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, vuelidate

`package.json`

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vuelidate/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.44",
    "@vuelidate/validators": "^2.0.0-alpha.31",
    "sass": "^1.51.0",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.7",
    "vuetify": "^3.0.0-beta.1"
  }
}
```

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
import {defineNuxtConfig} from 'nuxt'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
    css: [
        'vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass'
    ],
    build: {
        transpile: ['vuelidate', 'vuetify']
    }
})
```

error:

> [nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] Object.defineProperty called
> on non-object   at Function.defineProperty ()     at
> $id_wZFjrS4KDu (./.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:5133:8)     at
> **instantiateModule** (./.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:39873:9)     at **ssrLoadModule** (./.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:39811:25)     at ssrImport (./.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:39836:13)     at
> $id_2nr4xYa2an (./.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:5114:37)     at async
> **instantiateModule** (./.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:39873:3)

I am trying to add vuelidate module to nuxt3 project. I couldn't find similar solution for Vuelidate module.

Comment: Can't reproduce. https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-dgx9p5?file=package.json,nuxt.config.ts Please provide minimal reproduction.